# Sharepoint List & Export to excel sheet

Tags: 2010, list, ribbon, document, excel

I read that we can store list items limitation for sharepoint 2010 is 30 million . Is this true ?

If yes , then can i have 25 million records in sharepoint list , and use "export to excel sheet" and it will work fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is true, as per technet.

```
   Items 30,000,000 per list Supported
    You can create very large lists using standard views, site hierarchies, and metadata navigation. This value may vary depending on the number of columns in the list and the usage of the list.
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ListLibrary

But milage vary as in the description mentioned that its depend how many columns of different type.

I dont have a list this much items, so only way to check is test it.

I dont think so it's good idea to have list with 25Million items, this will be big performance hit on your site.

Comment: Yes , we have a list with folder structure . And the list has grown to 1 million records now . currently I want to find a archiving mechanism .

Comment: check this one http://referpages.com/wp/2012/04/101/

Comment: Thanks but i created a powershell script to move the list items to another list .

Comment: that's fine, if you automate via powershell it will be fine...above is automated thing once setup it work all the time...chioces are yours